# How to make a 500-1000ms timer circuit

Tags: timer

There are countless applications for delays of a few hundred milliseconds up to a few seconds. I have not been able to find some elegant solution, but I am sure that there must be a way, and that some of the expertise in here has a neat little circuit that is much better than whatever I can come up with.

And before I get the obvious answer: A 555 with a 1000uF cap is a fun breadboard experiment, but the huge electrolytic capacitor is absolutely impractical on any "real" miniaturized PCB's. Surely there must be a more practical/professional way.

I find it really strange that the big IC manufacturers doesn't have a simple sot-23 delay timer. Components such as TLP5010 is real close, but not quite bullseye. It can be coerced into a functional circuit with some additional components, but it still feels like a square wheel. So without any off-the-shelf options: Please share your favorite timer circuit.

Comment: A 555's timing depends on the capacitor *and* the resistor, so you can use a smaller cap with a big resistor. Still it's not a great choice if you need precision or low power consumption. There are timer/counters that run by counting pulses from a crystal oscillator. Maybe look into those?

Comment: "Share your favorite circuit" is not how this site works. You need to be very clear and specific about what you need, and don't just ask for an "elegant" solution.

Comment: Please take the [Tour] to learn how the site works.

Comment: Requirements? Input characteristics (active low/high, pulse width)? Output characteristics? Accuracy requirement? Some least to most accurate choices: 74AC14 with RC & diode, 555, MCU w/o crystal, MCU w/crystal.

Comment: You can use a microcontroller with internal factory-calibrated RC to get much better unadjusted precision than is possible with a 555. Or a CMOS 555 with a high value resistor. Or a 74HC123. A million solutions are possible. The right one depends on the application and other factors.

Comment: Try 10M 0.1uF and a single CMOS Schmitt Trigger in 603 , SMT parts <1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> find it really strange that the big IC manufacturers doesn't have a...

But they do! Analogue Devices [TimerBlox](https://www.analog.com/en/products/clock-and-timing/timerblox.html). There's a lot of them and they can do many things, but in a nutshell, they'll do 1 us to 39 days. Better than a 555.

Simple application from one of the data sheets:-

[image: timer]

'programmed' like so:-

[image: programming]

Comment: Power up. | Wait 39 days for output to go high. | Adjust trimpot. | Cycle power and repeat. I think some of the others in the series might let you monitor the internal clock. This would make calibration much faster.

Comment: @Transistor I'm absolutely sure that you're right, but I have to get to the off licence...